# How we can include/alternate "ON" keyword in JPQL

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, jpql

I have two tables where I want to have left join, my query looks following

> SELECT
>   * FROM BP_USER a LEFT JOIN BP_USER_BUSINESS b ON a.bpin = b.bpin;

When I tried to include ON in jpql, it raises an exception, kindly share the way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously that is SQL not JPQL, there is no asterisk in JPQL. Similarly "ON" clauses on joins is only present in JPA2.1 and not in earlier versions. Some implementations (like [DataNucleus JPA](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_2/)) already provide this, but yours maybe doesn't. If you're limited to an implementation which doesn't allow it yet then you have to put the *ON clause* into the WHERE clause of the JPQL